# hyperlink not highlighted in UILabel with NSAttributedText in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, hyperlink, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I am displaying a label with an attributed text.  The label contains some hyper links. 
I understand that these are only clickable in a textView however I thought that they would appear blue and underlined in a UILabel which has NSAttributedText.

**In my case the link is not any different than the other text (not blue or underlined).  Is there any property of the UILabel I need to change to make the link appear blue inside a UILabel?**

```
let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName: self.defaultFont(), NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: style]
let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "www.somelink.com", attributes: attributes)
label.attributedText = attributedString
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `NSLinkAttributeName` attribute to your `NSAttributedString` like this:

```
attributedString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: "www.somelink.com", range: attributedString.string.rangeOfString("www.somelink.com"))
```

Please check the range for your needs.

Comment: In my case the text can contain random user entered links.  How can I detect any link rather than a specific one?  Or date/phone for that matter?  I am trying to replicate the behaviour of a UITextView in appearance without the clickable feature.

Comment: Swift 3.0, you should use `NSMutableAttributedString` instead of `NSAttributedString`

Answer (score 1):

You need NSLinkAttributeName.  Above answer should work.

```
let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName: self.defaultFont(), NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: style]
let attributedString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: "www.somelink.com", range: attributedString.string.rangeOfString("www.somelink.com"))
label.attributedText = attributedString
```